# can't run android browser tests against SauceLabs using Intern 3

Tags: intern, saucelabs

Has anyone been able to run Android tests against SauceLabs using Intern 3?  It just fails on startup up for me.

AFAICT SauceLabs supports Selendroid (see https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/appium/), so it's not a problem with using the desupported AndroidDriver.

I used this environment setting:

```
    { browserName: "Browser", appiumVersion: "1.4.11", deviceName: "Android Emulator",
        deviceOrientation: "portrait", platformVersion: "5.1", platformName: "Android",
        automationName: "selendroid" }
```

But there's no change if I specify / don't specify automationName.

Comment: Having the same issue. Been trying out different configurations for android, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was finally able to get this working by using:

```
{ browserName: "android", platform: "Linux", version: "5.1",
deviceName: "Android Emulator" }
```